# SBT missing dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

I am trying to build my first project with SBT. I need to add some jars to it. my build.sbt looks like:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"

name := "abc"

version := "1.2.3"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.1",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.1"
)
```

but project does not compile saying

```
object slf4j is not a member of package org
```

which Im assuming is caused by the dependency not being on the class path. How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Scala, if you couldn't download a dependency the message would read `unresolved dependency ....`. Can you post your import statement wherever it is you're trying to use `slf4j`?

Comment: import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

Comment: Did you `reload` your configuration?

Comment: if you mean by calling reload, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it appears the directory structure was incorrect. My src directory was under project/ which appears to have been the problem. Might have copied sources to the wrong place.

Comment: Sources under `project/` are part of your build definition, not part of your main codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following import statement instead

```
import _root_.org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IntelliJ, go to `View > Tools Window > SBT` and in the SBT window, click the refresh icon (tooltip reads: Refresh All Projects).

Then try rebuilding. If you run `sbt compile` from the command line, modify your question to include the full error output.

slf4j is not being resolved from your local classpath. It's been pulled in by SBT (using Ivy under the hood) to pull it from the central maven repository. As the other comment stated, it seems like your editor is trying to compile your project using the older version of your `build.sbt` file; therefore not pulling in the dependency.

In InteliJ when you modify the `build.sbt`, it should popup a message at the top asking if you want to refresh the project. This might be in a different location if you use a different editor. Running `sbt` from the command line will always use the currently saved version of your `build.sbt`.